# Converting an ndarray image into a grayscale image with the same array shape

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I'm trying to write a python function that takes an image ndarray as a parameter and returns an ndarray of the grayscale version of that image using broadcasting.

My main issue right now is that my resulting image does not have the same shape (800, 400, 3) as the original.

Edit: it turns out that I had just forgotten to convert the resulting array into np.uint8

Comment: could you be a bit more specific: in what way does the result of the first bit of code not work?

Comment: why is it important to have the shape (800, 400, 3)? this last dimension 3 is for the colour layers which one does not need when using grayscale. of course, one can add this dimension by repeating the pixel value 3 times

Answer (score 0):

Your first `convert_bw` function don't have any problem, I think problem is how you see the result image (The library you use can't show you the result well). for example you can see the result by following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
bw = convert_bw(img)
plt.imshow(bw.astype(np.uint8))
```

It worked for me.